# Export a matrix with symbolic variables from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have a matrix with symbolic variable in MATLAB like this:

```
syms x
f = [x^2 x^3 x^4];
save ('sym.mat','f')
```

Thus I saved the `f` matrix as `sym.mat`. Now I want to import this matrix into python. So I tried this:

```
import scipy.io as sio
matrix = sio.loadmat('sym.mat')
sym = matrix['f']
```

But it didn't work. I got this error, which is just a regular python `keyerror`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'f'
```

However if `f` is not a symbolic matrix then this code works fine. Any ideas how I can deal with these matrices with symbolic variables?

Comment: What are the `keys` of `matrix`?  Give us an idea of what `loadmat` returned.  My guess is that MATLAB has saved a class and/or function that can't be translated into `numpy` structures.  I seen problems in previous SO questions with MATLAB functions and dates.

Comment: I see from other posts that you already know about `sympy`.  `numpy` and `scipy` don't have any symbolic functionality, so `loadmat` couldn't return the MATLAB equivalent even if it 'understood' `syms`.  The best you can do is some how recreate them in `sympy`.

Answer (score 1):

Scipy can't load MATLAB symbolic variables.

The best way to deal with your problem is to convert your Symbolic matrix into Matrix of chars(not matlab strings since it will cause errors too)

So here is what I mean:

In MATLAB, you can do something like that:

```
syms x
f = [x^2 x^3 x^4];
for i = 1:numel(f)
    if i == 1
        f2 = char(f(i));
    else
        f2 = [f2 ',' char(f(i))];

    end
end

save('sym.mat','f2')
```

This will display:

```
x^2,x^3,x^4
```

Now, In python you could do something like that:

```
import scipy.io as sio
path = 'H:\MatlabScripts'
matrix = sio.loadmat(path + '\sym.mat')
sym = matrix['f2'][0].split(',')
print(sym)
```

The result will be:

```
['x^2', 'x^3', 'x^4']
```